# C++ List sort function

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I don't know how to correctly implement the a sort for a list in C++. I am getting the build errors:

> 'Ranker::compare': function call missing argument list; use `'&Ranker::compare'` to create a pointer to member

How do I correctly implement my sort function for the list?

Ranker.h:

```
list<Competitor*> sorted;
```

Ranker.cpp:

```
bool Ranker::compare(Competitor* first, Competitor* second) {
    if (first->getTime() < second->getTime())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int Ranker::addList(Competitor* starter) {
    sorted.push_back(starter);
    sorted.sort(compare);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make rankor a simple functor:

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(Competitor* first, Competitor* second) const {
        return first->getTime() < second->getTime();
    }
};

// STUFF
sorted.sort(Compare());
```

Or if you have C++11

```
sorted.sort([](Competitor* first, Competitor* second) {
          return first->getTime() < second->getTime();
           });
```

Answer (score 5):

`Ranker::compare()` is a member function. Member functions are tied to instances. Try using either a static method or a "free" function.

Answer (score 0):

The function `Ranker::compare()` actually has *three* arguments: In addition to the two `Competitor` objects, it also takes an implicit pointer to the object as parameter. However, the binary predicate passed do `std::list<...>::sort()` only takes two parameters.

The easiest fix is probably to make the function a `static` member. Not, however, that this is probably **not** the fastest approach because function pointers can rarely be inlined. If you want to reduce the function call overhead, you might want to encapsulate the logic into a a suitable function object:

```
struct RankerCompare {
    bool operator()(Competitor const* first, Competitor const* second) const {
        return first->getTime() < second->getTime();
    }
};
...
sorted.sort(RankerCompare());
```

BTW, a Boolean doesn't become more Boolean by returning `true` or `false` from a conditional statement! It is perfectly OK to return a Boolean value directly!